# Что стоит делать, если на ваш вопрос никто не отвечает?

Tags: обсуждение

хотел уточнить какие действия необходимо сделать с собственным вопросом, чтобы он показался новым людям или на него нашелся ответ? В данный момент, я открыл вопрос и с течением какого-то времени на вопрос никто не ответил, что порекомендуете сделать в этом случае?

Comment: можно начать с чтения справки: [Что делать, если никто не отвечает на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Классический способ - объявить конкурс, чтобы вопрос появился в соответствующем [списке конкурсных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Bounties). Но для этого надо чтобы кто-то пожертвовал своей репутацией, если у автора её недостаточно, это может сделать другой участник, который так же заинтересован в получении ответа на поставленный вопрос.

Следующий способ - вносить в вопрос уточняющие/дополняющие или улучшающие так или иначе вопрос правки, чтобы он поднимался в списке вопросов и его увидело больше людей. Здесь, главное, не злоупотреблять со слишком частым и бестолковым редактированием. Так же стоит учитывать, что некоторые смотрят вопросы по новизне, и как бы вы его не редактировали, на глаза таким людям он скорее всего уже не попадёт.

Ещё важно выбрать для вопроса правильные метки, посмотрите на список популярных меток и выберите первую подходящую.

Comment: По новизне - это как? Как раз же правки будут поднимать наверх?

Comment: @Qwertiy "новые" vs "текущие"

Comment: А как узнать, какие правки необходимо внести для поднятие вопроса в списке? Например, если вопрос общего характера, не имеющий какой-либо конкретики, то какие правки вы бы рекомендовали вносить?
Насчет 1 и 3 совета, я буду брать во внимание, спасибо!

Comment: @Mikhail любая правка поднимает вопрос в списке. Другое дело в том, что есть вкладка [Новые](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest), а есть [Текущие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Active). Некоторые предпочитают смотреть только через вкладку Новые, поэтому сколько бы вы не редактировали, старые вопросы там не поднимаются. Но это частный случай.